How to skip asynchronous method obfuscation
Configuration file
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Obfuscator>
  <Var name="InPath" value="." />
  <Var name="OutPath" value=".\Obfuscator_Output" />
  <Var name="KeyFile" value=".\test.snk" />

  <Var name="ReuseNames" value="true" />
  <Var name="RenameProperties" value="true" />
  <Var name="RenameEvents" value="true" />
  <Var name="RenameFields" value="true" />
  <Var name="UseUnicodeNames" value="true" />
  <Var name="HideStrings" value="true" />
  <Var name="OptimizeMethods" value="true" />
  <Var name="SuppressIldasm" value="true" />

  <Module file="$(InPath)\BasicExampleExe.exe" />
  <Module file="$(InPath)\BasicExampleLibrary.dll"  >
   
    <SkipStringHiding type="BasicExampleLibrary.Base1" name="MethodA" />
    <SkipStringHiding type="BasicExampleLibrary.Base1" name="MethodB" />
    
  </Module>
</Obfuscator>

public async void MethodA( int param1 ) {
    
    const string DefaultMediaType = "application/json";
    var data = new StringContent("testtest", Encoding.UTF8, DefaultMediaType);

    string displayText = "sfdsfsfsfddd";
    string test = "sfdsfdddddddddddddsfsfddd";

}


public void MethodB( int param1 )
 {
    const string DefaultMediaType = "application/json";
    var data = new StringContent("testtest", Encoding.UTF8, DefaultMediaType);

    string displayText = "sfdsfsfsfddd";
    string test = "sfdsfdddddddddddddsfsfddd";
 }

The result after obfuscation

I want to skip obfuscation for MethodA, but if they are asynchronous methods, the skip configuration does not work.
